# Rollout summary statistics not being monitored for CustomEnv using Stable-Baselines3

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines, openai-api

I am trying to train a custom environment using PPO via Stable-Baselines3 and OpenAI Gym. For some reason the rollout statistics are not being reported for this custom environment when I try to train the PPO model.

The code that I am using is below ( I have not included the  code for the CustomEnv for brevity):

```
env = CustomEnv(mode = "discrete")
env = Monitor(env, log_dir)
model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log = log_dir)

timesteps = 5000
for i in range(3):
  model.learn(total_timesteps = timesteps, reset_num_timesteps = False, tb_log_name = "PPO")
  model.save(f"{models_dir}/car_model_{timesteps * i}")
```

Below is an image demonstrating the output from the above code (on the right of the image), and the left side of the image demonstrates the usual output from a dummy environment that I am using for debugging.

[image: On the left we have the usual output from model.learn() applied to a dummy environment, with rollout statistics being reported. On the right is my custom environment, where only 'time' and 'train' statistics are being reported.]

I have already tried adding the line of code:

```
env = Monitor(env, log_dir)
```

But that doesnt change the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: There was an edge case where the environment was not ending, and the done variable remained False indefinitely.

After fixing this bug, the Rollout statistics reappeared.

Comment: how is done=False relating to rollout statistics not appearing?